# How can show a canvas between 2 usercontrols?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, kinect

I have an Canvas on my Mainwindow, that supports skeletal tracking. This is shown in the mainwindow in the button  space.
But i have a settingsPage (is a usercontrol that a child of the contentGrid of the MainWindow) and i would like to Show or Collapse this canvas, so u can see it or cant see it in the mainwindow. I cant create a new instance because the skeletal tracking is being used with the kinect. So i have to work with the only instance that is created while loading the program.
I can use some help, so i can solve this problem. Thx

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand fully the question, but does not play with the Canvas "Visibility" Property ( = Visible / Hidden or Collapsed ) solve your issue ?

depending on your preferences you might want to bind it / change it in code / change it with an event+event handler.